# Simulink: 'To workspace' for a scalar value

Tags: matlab, simulink

I would like to export one scalar variable from a Simulink Diagram to the Matlab Workspace.

[image: Simulink Diagram]

Although I know that the value of 'Chemin' can be changed during the simulation, I am only interested in exporting the initial value to the workspace; I do not want a TimeSerie variable (like the 'To Workspace' block would do), I only one want scalar value.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Without knowing much about simulink: Would it be possible to just call the toworkspace block the first time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do what you want. Everything in Simulink is time-based so you have to save the entire variable as a function of time to the workspace. However, you can add a [model callback](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/model-callbacks.html) in `StopFcn` that extracts just the first value and clears the time-dependent variable from the workspace, e.g.:

```
chemin_0 = chemin(1); % assuming chemin is the name of the time-dependent variable saved to workspace
clear chemin
```

The `StopFcn` callback is executed after the simulation stops.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this pretty easily with an Enabled Subsystem.  Make the enable signal false at all times except t=0 by using a constant (=0) and an Initial Condition block (=1), as per the following picture.

[image: High level model]
Inside the Enabled Subsystem have

[image: Inside the subsystem]
with the save format set to be Array.  The simout variable will then be a scalar valued number.